# Disable Side Menu in Ionic Cordova App Splash/Intro Screen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to disable/hide the side menu on the Splash/Intro page only.

I tried adding this code to intro.ts:

```
import {  MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

 constructor( public menuCtrl: MenuController,){ }
     ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
  }
```

But while building it throws error:

```
import {  MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
       constructor( public menuCtrl: MenuController,){ }
        ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
     }
```

Is there any way to do this. I am using:
Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
```

Thanks in advance.

This is the full page code of intro.ts

```
    import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ConfigService } from '../../services/config';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';
import { MultiselectorPage } from '../multiselector/multiselector';




@Component({
  selector: 'page-intro',
  templateUrl: 'intro.html'
})
export class Intro {
  @ViewChild('IntroTabs') introTabs: Slides;
  multiselectorpage = MultiselectorPage;
    tabsPage = TabsPage;
    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
      private config:ConfigService,
        private storage:Storage) {
    }
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.config);
  }
  goToHome(){
    if(this.config.multisite.enable_multisite){
       this.navCtrl.push(this.multiselectorpage);
    }else{
        this.storage.set('introShown', true);
        this.config.initialize();
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.tabsPage);
    }


  }
  proceed(){
    let index = this.introTabs.getActiveIndex();
    index++;
    this.introTabs.slideTo(index, 500);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the ion-menu-button off the toolbar and instead of using:

```
this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
```

you can use:

```
this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(false);
```

after doing this, there's no way to open menu by tapping or swiping.
Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But where do I place the code? 
After placing it under constructor, I got the error same error.

Comment: in ionViewWillEnter() should be fine

Comment: Thanks for following up, really appreciate it. Unfortunately no, i got an error that basically said ionviewwillenter() is not valid.

Comment: dude there is a very important thing, you HAVE TO make sure that you write ionViewWillEnter() not ionviewwillenter() or not IonViewWillEnter().

Comment: @Rohithvsn if it didn't work put my solution and your solution in constractor instead of ionViewWillEnter and try again.